# Disable/redirect a route given a particular time range

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Hello I am wondering how to disable or change a route in Rails based on a ranged time of day.

For instance redirect /support/livechat to a different route or url during 11pm-5am.

Comment: Could you do it in the controller with a before_action that checks the time of day and redirects to a different route during those hours?

Comment: @trueinViso I wrote an example of how I might do it simply. feedback welcome.

Comment: Looks good to me, I can't really think of an easier way off the top of my head.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I am leaning towards currently.
feedback and ideas welcome.

```
before_action :route_based_on_timezone, only: [:livesupport]

def route_based_on_timezone

  current_hour = Time.now.in_time_zone("Pacific Time (US & Canada)").hour

  if [23,0,1,2,3,4,5].include?(current_hour)
    # redirect
  else
    # no nothing and allow user to continue on
  end
end
```